# How to print current logging configuration used by the python logging module?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm using the python `logging` module.

I update the logging config using `logging.dictConfig()`.

I would like a way to read the current configuration (e.g. level) used by each logger and print it.

How can I get and print this information?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree

Comment: Are you asking how to get the current level for a particular logger?

Comment: @SimeonVisser, thanks, logging_tree is awesome, can you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [Simeon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31599940/4794#comment51151416_31599940), the [logging_tree package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree) lets you print out the details of the current logging configuration.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger('a')
>>> logging.getLogger('a.b').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.getLogger('x.c')
>>> from logging_tree import printout
>>> printout()
<--""
   Level WARNING
   |
   o<--"a"
   |   Level NOTSET so inherits level WARNING
   |   |
   |   o<--"a.b"
   |       Level DEBUG
   |
   o<--[x]
       |
       o<--"x.c"
           Level NOTSET so inherits level WARNING
>>> # Get the same display as a string:
>>> from logging_tree.format import build_description
>>> print(build_description()[:50])
<--""
   Level WARNING
   |
   o<--"a"
   |   Leve
```

Answer (score 9):

Logging configuration are stored in `logging.root.manager`.

From there you can access every logging parameters, example : `logging.root.manager.root.level` to get the logging level of your root logger.

Any other loggers can be accessed through `logging.root.manager.loggerDict['logger_name']`.

Here is an example on how to get the formatter used by a custom logger:

```
>>> import logging
>>> import logging.config
>>> config = {"version": 1,
...     "formatters": {
...         "detailed": {
...             "class": "logging.Formatter",
...             "format": "%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(processName)-10s %(message)s"}},
...     "handlers": {
...         "console": {
...             "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
...             "level": "WARNING"},
...         "file": {
...             "class": "logging.FileHandler",
...             "filename": "mplog.log",
...             "mode": "a",
...             "formatter": "detailed"},
...         "foofile": {
...             "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
...             "filename": "mplog-foo.log",
...             "mode": "a",
...             "formatter": "detailed",
...             "maxBytes": 20000,
...             "backupCount": 20}},
...     "loggers": {
...         "foo": {
...             "handlers": ["foofile"]}},
...     "root": {
...         "level": "DEBUG",
...         "handlers": ["console", "file"]}}
>>> logging.config.dictConfig(config)
>>> logging.root.manager.loggerDict['foo'].handlers[0].formatter._fmt
'%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(processName)-10s %(message)s'
```

Handlers parameters can also be found in `logging._handlers.data`.

```
>>> logging._handlers.data['file']().__dict__
 {'baseFilename': '/File/Path/mplog.log',
  'mode': 'a',
  'encoding': None,
  'delay': False,
  'filters': [],
  '_name': 'file',
  'level': 0,
  'formatter': <logging.Formatter object at 0x7ff13a3d6df0>,
  'lock': <unlocked _thread.RLock object owner=0 count=0 at 0x7ff13a5b7510>,
  'stream': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/File/Path/mplog.log' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>}
```

Comment: This is great, as it does not introduce additional (dev) dependencies. The `logging_tree` package, mentioned in the other answers, [uses this](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/logging_tree/blob/e2377057dcc3c46d9ad178ff7e337d4a2737d817/logging_tree/nodes.py#L15) under the hood.

Comment: Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250066

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is the logging level for a particular logger, then you can use - [`logger.getEffectiveLevel()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel) , this would give the integer value for the currently logging level for the logger, and then you can use it with [`logging.getLevelName()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLevelName) , to get the string representation for that level.

Example -

```
>>> import logging
>>> l = logging.getLogger(__name__)
>>> l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.getLevelName(l.getEffectiveLevel())
'DEBUG'
```

Comment: Thank you, Anand.  My question was more about how to print the config of all loggers.  Simeon answered it, but I appreciate your suggestion.