# See current logging config in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, logging

I am setting up logging in Django, but for some reason I see no logs appear. Django uses Python's `logging` module (I use Python 2.7).

Is there a way I can see the currently configured logging setup, something like a `logging.getConfigDict()` or so?

Comment: you can see your logging config via the `LOGGING` settings in django, you can use the Django Debug Toolbar to see the value. Or with the `./manage.py shell`, you can do `from django.conf import settings;print(settings.LOGGING)`.

Comment: see also django default behavior, if DEBUG is False, it's not gonna log to the console: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/#django-s-default-logging-configuration

Comment: It turned out that I was using another settings file... but I still wonder how I can ask the standard library's logging module what its current settings are. Django has its own logging settings as well, what is in LOGGING is not necessarily all that is configured in logging.

Comment: Check out `logging.root.manager` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742295).

Comment: @damio `settings.LOGGING` does not represent the complete logging configuration. As can be seen [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/db7bb3b64e469fbb5c79e7b5b2fcb890434aa60f/django/utils/log.py#L67), and as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging), Django first applies its default logging configuration, then updates that with `settings.LOGGING`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the `logging_tree` module for that:

`pip install logging_tree`

and then (via `./manage.py shell`)

```
import logging_tree
logging_tree.printout()
```

More infos: http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/logging_tree/